# What is the most efficient way to check for whether integer is odd?

Tags: c#

how do I get the lowest order bit (or any bit) without the modulo operation (since the number may be arbitrarily large) on a series of bits that represent a number in base 2, assuming I know the bit structure of the datatype, in C#, in the most lightweight manner possible?

Comment: What made you think you needed to create a byte array?

Comment: if ((value & 1) != 0) Console.WriteLine("odd");  That test takes 0.25 cpu cycles, can't get more "low-level" than that :)

Comment: @JonSkeet "GetBytes" is what I was looking at.  wanted to avoid mod, since this is a custom integer (Unity is not compatible with .Numerics)...just pushing through the learning curve.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom integer"? It's really very unclear what you're talking about here. If you mean you're using some Unity-specific integer type, you should *very, very clearly* have stated that in the question. You've said that Dmitry's answer works, which suggests you're only dealing with `int` after all...

Comment: @JonSkeet no, I am dealing with an array of ulong in an implementation of an abstract `Integer` type, which I am using to split between the code specific to the array of ulong (for instance, the fast multiplication, mod exponentiation, etc. vs. the primality testing, RSA, odd/even--all of which can be in the abstract section) that I am writing for an RSA implementation that I coded up just a second ago.  Don't see why I need to publish everything for a simple question.  Just can't use "BigInteger" on the Unity Mono. So, why not code it myself...? Why not use all bytes--that makes the algs easy

Comment: @JonSkeet haven't made all my design decisions yet...do I have to, before I get the information that answers my question?

Comment: So what is your actual *question* about? That's still very unclear. What type are you trying to test for oddness - one of the primitive types, or something else? If it's one of the primitive types, the Unity aspect is completely irrelevant and I still don't see what `GetBytes()` had to do with anything. If it's *not* one of the primitive types, you should make that clear in your question. "Don't see why I need to publish everything for a simple question" - you need to include everything that's relevant, ideally a [mcve]. You didn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet actual question: how do I get the lowest order bit without the modulo operation on a series of bits that represent a number in base 2, assuming I know the bit structure of the datatype, in C#, in the most lightweight manner possible.

Comment: @bordeo: Without knowing what data type you're using to represent those bits, we can't tell. Maybe you're using a byte array. Maybe you're using a `BitArray`. Maybe you're using a single `int`. Maybe you're using a `MemoryStream`... what answer would you expect to cover all of those? Why not just ask about one specific type, ideally with a [mcve], and make the question answerable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do a bitwise AND with 1, which will get you the last bit.

```
int n = 3;
bool odd = (n & 1) == 1;
```